# Laravel Polymorphic Many to Many relationship

Tags: laravel, polymorphism

I am *very* new to polymorphic relationships and am struggling on my first task.  My real life scenario is complicated, so for the purpose of this question, I have simplified it a little.

I have a range of products. Each of these products can be '*tagged*' to one or more "Categories", "Brand" and "Consumer". For example:

[image]

I figured with this setup, I would need a table for my polymorphic relationships as below:

[image]

I have created a new Taggable class which contains the following

```
<?php

    namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Taggable extends Model
    {
        public function taggable()
        {
            return $this->morphTo();
        }
    }
```

...and added a method to my Product class:

```
public function taggedCategories()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Taggable::class, 'taggable');
}
```

Finally, in my ProductController, I am trying to retrieve all products with their relationships as such:

```
$products = Product::with('taggedCategories')
```

Whilst this isn't producing an error, there are no categories returned in my results.  Looking at the SQL output in LaravelDebugBar, I see the following SQL.

```
select * from `taggables` where `taggables`.`taggable_id` in (1) and `taggables`.`taggable_type` = 'App\Models\Product'
```

This clearly is not right, but I cannot for love nor money figure out where I have gone wrong. I feel I am close, but not quite there.

Can anyone explain what is wrong? Also, would I need to do something different for getting the "Brand" as this is a one-to-many relationship, not many-to-many?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model structure is going to be like:

```
class Categories extends Model
{        
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'productable');
    }
}

class Brand extends Model
{        
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'productable');
    }
}

// and Consumers, ....
```

User Model:

```
class Product extends Model
{        
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Categories', 'productable');
    }

    public function brands()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Brunds', 'productable');
    }
}
```

Database schema:

```
categories
    id - integer
    ...

brands
    id - integer
    ...

consumer
    id - integer
    ...

productable
    product_id - integer
    productable_id - integer
    productable_type - string
```

Now, you can retrieve the relations:

```
$categories = App\Categories::find(1);
// retrieve product of a type
foreach ($categories->products as $product) {
    //
}

$product = App\Product::find(1);
// retrieve categories  of a product
foreach ($product->categories as $categories) {
    //
}
```

Actually, your type product (categories, brands, consumers) are productable.